# Qt App freezes occasionally when showing a new widget

Tags: c++, qt

My application has one main window (inherits from `QMainWindow`). The main window is parent to a `QTabWidget`, which acts as a sort of dialog that shows up when the user clicks a toolbar button on the main window. In addition, the main window has another toolbar button, which when clicked, calls `exec()` on a `QDialog`. While developing the app, I have noticed that once every 40 times or so, clicking one of the two buttons I have mentioned causes an empty widget to appear, but instead of the intended view being drawn, everything freezes. When I click the 'Close' button on the main window, my OS tells me that the application has stopped responding. There is never any way to recover from crashes like this, and I am usually forced to kill the app and restart.

The vexing thing about all this is that I cannot reproduce the crashes at will. They are impossible to predict, and often catch me off-guard. I am using Qt Creator. Nothing helpful is printed in the Creator console when the crashes occur.

Has anyone run into such an issue? How do I debug what is happening?

Btw I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, and my Qt Version is 5.4

EDIT

Gdb stacktrace:

```
#0  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
#1  0x00007f1ba3bf1b03 in QWaitCondition::wait(QMutex*, unsigned long) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007f1ba3bea277 in QReadWriteLock::lockForRead() ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#3  0x00007f1b9bf5ee4e in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#4  0x00007f1b9bf61d71 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#5  0x00007f1b9bf64e54 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#6  0x00007f1b904159d6 in dbus_connection_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3
#7  0x00007f1b9bf579f5 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#8  0x00007f1b9bfa78f5 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#9  0x00007f1ba3e5a326 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007f1ba510b8f4 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#11 0x00007f1ba510f506 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#12 0x00007f1ba3e25c84 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007f1ba3e28868 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007f1ba3e80123 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007f1ba283be04 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007f1ba283c048 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007f1ba283c0ec in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007f1ba3e80554 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
    () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#19 0x00007f1ba3e23eab in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#20 0x00007f1ba530a2ed in QDialog::exec() () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#21 0x0000000000425fe4 in MainWindow::AddNewDownload() ()
#22 0x00007f1ba3e57e7a in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007f1ba50fee52 in QAction::triggered(bool) () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#24 0x00007f1ba5100c77 in QAction::activate(QAction::ActionEvent) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#25 0x00007f1ba520b0b5 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#26 0x00007f1ba520b374 in QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#27 0x00007f1ba52cf89a in QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#28 0x00007f1ba514723c in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#29 0x00007f1ba52d0730 in QToolButton::event(QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#30 0x00007f1ba510b8f4 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#31 0x00007f1ba510f071 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#32 0x00007f1ba3e25c84 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#33 0x00007f1ba510df88 in QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool) () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#34 0x00007f1ba5162387 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#35 0x00007f1ba5164e78 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

Comment: Just pause the app and investigate the individual threads for possible deadlocks or race conditions.

Comment: My app is single-threaded.

Comment: Less to investigate ;) but are you sure? An empty qt widgets app on windows here has 5 threads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008511/is-it-possible-that-a-single-threaded-program-is-executed-simultaneously-on-more

Comment: Qt doesn't create new threads under the hood. You have to explicitly use QThreads.